# Using python to copy a jsonl.gz file from S3 to ABS and unzip along the way

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a Databricks notebook to copy a jsonl.gz file from S3 to ABS (my ABS container is already mounted), and need the file to be unzipped at the end of the process. The filenames will be fed into the notebook using the 'directory' and 'fileun' variables. An example filename is 'folder-date/0000-00-0000.jsonl.gz'.

I am having difficulty figuring out the exact syntax for this. Currently I am getting stuck on trying to read the jsonl.gz file into a dataframe. The error I get is "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>". Here is what I have so far, any help is appreciated:

```
fileun = dbutils.widgets.get("fileun")
directory = dbutils.widgets.get("directory")
file = fileun[:-3]
file_path=directory+fileun

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import boto3
import pyodbc
import gzip
import shutil

client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name='region',
    aws_access_key_id='key',
    aws_secret_access_key='key'
)

response=client.get_object(
    Bucket='bucket_name',
    Key=file_path
)

**df = pd.read_json(response, compression='infer')**

with gzip.open(response, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open(file, 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

writefile =  open('container_name' % (fileun), 'w') 
writefile.write(df)
writefile.close()
```

Here is a snippet from one of the files:

```
{
  "uid": "9a926d799f437b0d279c144dec2bcef7cd16db341bca6e7653246d960331d00a",
  "doc": {
    "snippet": {
      "authorProfileImageUrl": null,
      "textDisplay": "@Keanu Corps  Same \"reasoning\" as the democrats. Even though inflation is getting worse.",
      "publishedAt": "2021-10-28T09:34:15.334995+0000",
      "authorChannelUrl": "/channel/UCsxSW7_bBsbFAjkh7ujctRA",
      "authorChannelId": {
        "value": "UCsxSW7_bBsbFAjkh7ujctRA"
      },
      "likeCount": 0,
      "videoId": "U2R_srS4TR4",
      "authorDisplayName": "The Video Game Hunger 01"
    },
    "crawlid": "-",
    "kind": "youtube#comment",
    "correlation_id": "195c9442-74d8-5003-baa3-7f1d05ef5aa6",
    "id": "UgznKXgYDDWUEjX0YaZ4AaABAg.9TvZiuGoiMM9U1jbFAWCTn",
    "parentId": "UgznKXgYDDWUEjX0YaZ4AaABAg",
    "is_reply": true,
    "timestamp": "2021-10-28T18:34:15.437543"
  },
  "system_timestamp": "2021-10-28T18:34:15.944581+00:00",
  "norm_attribs": {
    "website": "github.com/-",
    "type": "youtube",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "type": "youtube_comment",
  "norm": {
    "author": "The Video Game Hunger 01",
    "domain": "youtube.com",
    "id": "UgznKXgYDDWUEjX0YaZ4AaABAg.9TvZiuGoiMM9U1jbFAWCTn",
    "body": "@Keanu Corps  Same \"reasoning\" as the democrats. Even though inflation is getting worse.",
    "author_id": "UCsxSW7_bBsbFAjkh7ujctRA",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2R_srS4TR4&lc=UgznKXgYDDWUEjX0YaZ4AaABAg.9TvZiuGoiMM9U1jbFAWCTn",
    "timestamp": "2021-10-28T09:34:15.334995+00:00"
  },
  "organization_id": "-",
  "sub_organization_id": "default",
  "campaign_id": "-",
  "project_id": "default",
  "project_version_id": "default",
  "meta": {
    "relates_to_timestamp": [
      {
        "results": [
          "2021-10-28T09:34:15.334995+00:00"
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "Timestamp Extractor",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "post_type": [
      {
        "results": [
          "post"
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "Post Type Extractor",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "relates_to": [
      {
        "results": [
          "U2R_srS4TR4"
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "String Extractor",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "author_name": [
      {
        "results": [
          "The Video Game Hunger 01"
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "String Extractor",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "author_id": [
      {
        "results": [
          "UCsxSW7_bBsbFAjkh7ujctRA"
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "String Extractor",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "rule_matcher": [
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "metadata": {
              "campaign_title": "-",
              "project_title": "-",
              "maxdepth": 0
            },
            "sub_organization_id": null,
            "description": null,
            "project_version_id": "-",
            "rule_id": "2569463",
            "rule_tag": "-",
            "rule_type": "youtube_keyword",
            "project_id": "-",
            "appid": "nats-main",
            "organization_id": "-",
            "value": "طالبان شلیک",
            "campaign_id": "-",
            "node_id": null
          }
        ],
        "attribs": {
          "website": "github.com/-",
          "source": "Explicit",
          "type": "youtube",
          "version": "1.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your json inside the .gz file, it's tough to say exactly how to help.

This is what I use to download from .gz from s3 directly to dataframe.

```
import gzip
import json
s3sr = boto3.resource('s3')
obj =s3sr.Object(bucket, key)
data = json.loads(gzip.decompress(obj.get()['Body'].read()))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And if opening .gz from local, I use this

```
with gzip.open(fullpath, 'rb') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I added a snippet from one of the files to my original question so you can see the structure. When I run the code you provided, I get this error: "JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 32592)"

Comment: unclear what's happening. if i take that json snippet and put it in a file (gz or uncompressed), I can read it in to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally ended up working to copy the file, but I am losing the individual objects within the file and they are showing up on just one line:

```
fileun = dbutils.widgets.get("fileun")
directory = dbutils.widgets.get("directory")
key=directory+fileun

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import boto3
import pyodbc
import os
import gzip
import shutil
import json

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3',
  aws_access_key_id=[key_id],
  aws_secret_access_key= [access_key]
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= directory+fileun)
for obj in objects:
  path, filename = os.path.split(obj.key)
my_bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename)

with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f_in:
    with open(file, 'wb') as f_out:
      shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

with open(file) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

jinsert = df.to_json(orient="records")
writefile =  open('[container_name]' % (file), 'w') 
writefile.write(jinsert)
writefile.close()
```